# How to write the Poincare transformation for an arbitary path in Minkowski space?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, poincare-symmetry

So lets Say for arguments sake we have some vector $V^{a}$ and we drag it along some path $\gamma_{1}$ in Minkowski space $R^{3,1}$. For a straight path (represented by a vector $\Delta\overrightarrow{x}$, we can represent the change by a Poincare transformation $\Lambda$.

$$V^{\bar{a}}=\Lambda_{a}^{\bar{a}}V^{a}$$

Where the Poincare transformation can be represented as:

$$\Lambda_{a}^{\bar{a}}=exp\left\{ \frac{i}{2}\left(\Delta x^{\mu}P_{\mu}+\Delta\varTheta^{\mu\nu}J_{\mu\nu}\right)\right\}$$

Where the $P_{\mu}$ and $J_{\mu\nu}$ represent the infinitesimal generators of translation and the Lorentz group respectively (and the $\Delta\varTheta^{\mu\nu}$ and angle of rotation of the vector upon transformation). Note, I've dropped the transformation indices to unclutter notation.

We could consider our path to be a series of $N$ such transformations each labeled by $i$. In this case our transformation becomes a composition of all transformations:

$$\Lambda_{a}^{\bar{a}}=\prod_{i=0}^{N}exp\left\{ \frac{i}{2}\left(\Delta x_{i}^{\mu}P_{\mu}+\Delta\varTheta_{i}^{\mu\nu}J_{\mu\nu}\right)\right\} $$

Since all of the transformations are elements of the Poincare group, the total transformation also will be. We can find the transformation for a smooth path in the standard way:

$$\Lambda_{a}^{\bar{a}}=\mathscr{L\mathit{im}}\left(N\rightarrow\infty,\Delta x_{i}\Delta\varTheta_{i}\rightarrow0\right)\prod_{i=0}^{N}exp\left\{ \frac{i}{2}\left(\Delta x_{i}^{\mu}P_{\mu}+\Delta\varTheta_{i}^{\mu\nu}J_{\mu\nu}\right)\right\} $$

Since we've operator valued matrices in the exponent we have to make use of the Cambell-Baker-Hausdorff formula:

$$exp(X)exp(Y)=exp\left(X+Y+\frac{1}{2}[X,Y]+\cdots\right)$$

The first $\left(X+Y\right)$ term is super easy:

$$ln\left(\Lambda_{a}^{\bar{a}}\right)=\frac{i}{2}\left\{ \intop_{\gamma}\left(dx^{\mu}P_{\mu}+d\varTheta^{\mu\nu}J_{\mu\nu}\right)+\cdots\right\} $$

Where the integration is performed over the path. It's the second term that's giving me troubles. Looking at it again for a moment as a series of discrete transformations, let's say three for example we have:

$$secondterm=\frac{1}{2}\left\{ \left[\Delta x_{1}^{\mu}P_{\mu},\Delta x_{2}^{\mu}P_{\mu}\right]+\left[\Delta x_{1}^{\mu}P_{\mu},\Delta x_{3}^{\mu}P_{\mu}\right]+\left[\Delta x_{2}^{\mu}P_{\mu},\Delta x_{3}^{\mu}P_{\mu}\right]\right\} $$

Where I've only shown the translation terms for clarity. In the continuum limit, I see there should be a double integral over what lookes like a two-form? It looks like there will be a Dirac delta function as well since in: $\sum_{i,j}\left[\Delta x_{i}P,\Delta x_{j}P\right]\quad i\neq j $

I'm a little confused here but I know there's a way. Sorry if the question's formulated poorly. I get that this is only the second in an infinite series of such terms, but I swear I've seen the solution to this (or something similar) somewhere.

Obviously I've too much free time over christmas. Merry winter Solstice!!!

Comment: The $\delta$ function should not appear, you have two $dx$ but also two integrals. I think what you need in this case is the path ordered exponential. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential

Comment: @Mane.andrea   Thanks! that might help! Also, do you think If I was to work with the double cover instead, maybe  a braiding identity would become useful? I'm still learning a lot of this. Thanks again! (:

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that, hopefully someone else might be more helpful.